# Is there a function to just add new documents to the database when you have a JSON array of new and existing documents?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm getting JSON data from an API which updates on a regular basis with new objects. As expected, whenever I run the function to get the info from the API and then insert into the DB, the database adds all of the documents again.

Is there a way to only add any new objects from the API as documents, and ignore any existing documents.

I'm aware that a new ObjectID is created each time, so they are in fact never going to be duplicates. I've looked into compound indexing, but I can't wrap my head around how this can fix my issue.

```
    let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?location=london&q=graduate');

    var importantSOInfo = [];

    const handleError = function() {
        console.error(err);
        // handle your error
    };

    feed.items.map(job => {

        job = new Job ({
            title: job.title,
            url: job.link,
            categories: job.categories,
        });

        importantSOInfo.push(job);
    });

    Job.insertMany(importantSOInfo, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

})();
```

Comment: You'll have to fetch the items from the database, do deduplication application side and then update the database again. If monodb is not a necessity or you can switch the data store, then use a relational database like MySQL/PostgresQL and just create the id as a unique/primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) in your schema on `url` for example:

```
var YourSchema = new Schema({
    url: { 
        type: String, 
        unique: true,
        index: true
    },
    title: String
    //...
});
```

Since the `url` should be unique in `SO` to begin with you should not need a compound index really.

Comment: Very clear, thank you @Akrion! If a new object was added to the API would that be added to the Collection as a document or would nothing be added because we have other items in the API that are already there (duplicates)?